# StyleCop SA1620, I don't know how to resolve my XML Comments to its liking

Tags: c#, stylecop

I have the following code w/comments:  (It does compile)

```
/// <summary>
/// return a passing result of a particular type
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the value to be returned</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">the value to be returned</param>
/// <returns>a passing result</returns>
public static Result<T> Pass(T value)
{
    return new Result<T>()
    {
        Passed = true,
        Value = value
    };
}
```

I get the following *warning* with it:

> Warning   1   SA1620 : CSharp.Documentation : 
>   The typeparam tags in the documentation header must 
>   match the generic types for the method.

I did look at the help page for this error, which gives this explanation:

> To fix a violation of this rule, add and fill-in one   tag
>   for each generic type parameter on the element, and make sure  that
>   the  tags appear in the same order as the  element’s type
>   parameters.

And it has provided sample code:

```
/// <summary>
/// A sample generic class.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="S">The first generic type parameter.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="T">The second generic type parameter.</typeparam>
public class Class1<S, T>
{ 
}
```

I don't see anything about mine that breaks the standards it is showing, and I have tried various odd things, but I have no real idea of what I'm supposed to do here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way that this can compile is if this method is inside a `class` that is generic in `T`. This *method* doesn't have any type parameters. If it was generic, there would be type parameters after the name of the method:

```
public static Result<T> Pass<T>(T value)
{
    return new Result<T>()
    {
        Passed = true,
        Value = value
    };
}
```

But that's not the case with your method. So it must be:

```
class SomeClass<T>
{
  public static Result<T> Pass(T value)
  {
      return new Result<T>()
      {
          Passed = true,
          Value = value
      };
  }
}
```

And any documentation about the type parameter belongs up at the class level. E.g.:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a result class
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of the value to be returned</typeparam>
public class Result<T>
{
    public bool Passed { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// return a passing result of a particular type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">the value to be returned</param>
    /// <returns>a passing result</returns>
    public static Result<T> Pass(T value)
    {
        return new Result<T>()
        {
            Passed = true,
            Value = value
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: the code compiles.  It is inside a class with this header:  public class Result<T>

Comment: The problem is that StyleCop doesn't like it.  I want to know why.

Comment: @WarpWars.Net - what I'm saying is that a `<typeparam>` element belongs in the documentation for the *class* and there should be **no** `<typeparam>` element in the documentation for the *method*.

Comment: that was it.  Sorry, I miss-understood your answer before.  The class did have that on it.  I just needed to delete the line from the method.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: (thanks for adding the comments to your code samples, it really helps explain it better)